# Problems with decimal in iOS

Tags: ios, calculator

I have two questions about decimals on my calculator-app:

(1)How do I add a decimal button?

(2)If I type or calculate a big number on the calculator it shows this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuigto6vcok8rtk/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-12%20at%2016.22.44.png

Code: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zu6ijmbvredssoo/2cH4rzDd3E

The calculator works with buttons

Im using xcode 5

Comment: Basically your problem is that you want to identify numbers on the button rt??

Answer (score 0):

Your post is far too vague. Does your calculator app use an iOS keyboard, or do you have custom buttons? And what do you mean a "decimal button"? You want a button that inserts a decimal place in the number the user is typing?

How you do that depends on how your calculator app works.

I'm not going to download and examine your app for you - sorry. You need to provide a brief, complete explanation of how your app works now, and what you are trying having trouble doing.

As for the output, that's scientific notation, and is a quite common way to display large numbers. The "%g" (or "%G") format string switches to scientific notation automatically if the  exponent is large or small enough. Read the description of "%g" in the section of the Xcode docs on "Format Specifiers" for more information.

You probably want to create a custom NSNumberFormatter and use that to format your output number. That will give you more control than you get with stringWithFormat and the like.

Comment: I want to add a decimal point button to insert a , or . at the end of the number for a calculation like:'1.5 x 2 = 3' without it disappearing if I enter something else.